# Searching array of objects for item in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am trying to search through an array of objects for a value, but am having trouble getting the find_index to work. In my code below, I am trying to search for the name (joseph) in the array. Is this the best way? I want to return that object after I search and find it.

```
name = "joseph"

array = [{"login":"joseph","id":4,"url":"localhost/joe","description":null},
{"login":"billy","id":10,"url":"localhost/billy","description":null}]

arrayItem = array.find_index {|item| item.login == name}

puts arrayItem
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your array contains a Hash, with keys that are symbols (in hashes, `key: value` is a shorthand for `:key => value`). Therefore, you need to replace `item.login` with `item[:login]`:

```
name = "joseph"

array = [{"login":"joseph","id":4,"url":"localhost/joe","description":nil},
{"login":"billy","id":10,"url":"localhost/billy","description":nil}]

arrayIndex = array.find_index{ |item| item[:login] == name }

puts arrayIndex
```

The code above retrieves the index at which the sought object is in the array. If you want the object and not the index, use `find` instead of `find_index`:

```
arrayItem = array.find{ |item| item[:login] == name }
```

*Also, note that in Ruby, `null` is actually called `nil`.*

Comment: `find_index` returns the item's index, the OP probably wants `find`

Comment: w0lf's solution will return the first match.  If you want all matches, use `select` instead of `find`.